# How do I receive the entire output of the Watson Speech to Text SDK in Python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, ibm-watson

after a lot of testing, I was able to receive an output from the application i created in python to convert speech to text using IBM bluemix. code:

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import RecognizeCallback, AudioSource
import threading
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('xxxx')
service = SpeechToTextV1(authenticator=authenticator)
service.set_service_url('https://api.us-east.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com')

models = service.list_models().get_result()
print(json.dumps(models, indent=2))

model = service.get_model('en-US_BroadbandModel').get_result()
print(json.dumps(model, indent=2))

with open(join(dirname('__file__'), 'testvoice3.wav'),
          'rb') as audio_file:
    print(json.dumps(
        service.recognize(
            audio=audio_file,
            content_type='audio/wav',
            timestamps=True,
            word_confidence=True,model='en-US_NarrowbandModel',
        continuous=True).get_result(),
        indent=2))
```

I am receiving an output which looks like the below:

```
            [
              "no",
            [
              "their",
              0.41
            ],
            [
              "lives",
              0.1
            ],
            [
              "you",
              0.56
            ],
            [
              "take",
              1.0
            ],
            [
              "Kerr",
              0.95
            ],
            [
              "bye",
              0.4
            ],
            [
              "bye",
              0.99
            ]
          ]
        }
      ],
      "final": true
    }
  ],
  "result_index": 0
}
```

I just want to to receive the entire output in one place instead of this such format. I just want the transcript seperately from the confidence scores. So i can export this to a text file. How would i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That output is word confidence. There should be an entry in the output with the full text, most likely higher up in your listing.

To condense the output to only the transcript take out the options `word_confidence=True` and `timestamps=True`.

Comment: but what do i call to_csv? I do not understand which datafrme the output is stored in

Comment: `results[0].alternatives[0].transcript`

Comment: NameError: name 'results' is not defined

Comment: Add the code that looks at the response to your question, so we can see what you are doing.